# How to develop a Deep learning model for only two Imges ...?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, computer-vision

I am trying to build Deep learning model for only two Images. I have a two images of doors , one image is some what good and another is some what bad,
I want to identify the one is good and another  is bad , But I don't have a large amount of data, only I have two images, Please help me , how to build the Deep learning network and please share me any references..

Comment: i'm quite sure not even a human can intuit what you're looking for with just two images, nevermind an nn.

Comment: Why you want to use deep learning? I guess that there may be more suitable methods for such small dataset (e.g. classical computer vision techiques involving feature extraction as SIFT etc.)

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-shot_learning is close to what you described. You are still usually better off collecting much more training data.

Comment: Those models are first trained on large samples, then they are just re-trained on single images, so if someone has *only* two images, then such models would not learn anything reasonable.

Comment: Presumably one can use pre-trained models?